# Oracle External Table RECORDS DELIMITED BY '",\n"' not working

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, external-tables

I am trying to read large CSV files with lots of Newline characters in them.

this is how the data looks like in the CSV file.

```
                    "LastValueInRow",
"FirstValueInNextRow",
```

I would like to use **"** + **,** + **NEWLINE** + **"** as records delimiter to prevent it from reading all other return characters as new records.

The following code reads most CSV records correctly by using NEWLINE (**\n**) + **"**

```
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL 
    ( TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
      DEFAULT DIRECTORY "IMPORT_TEST"
      ACCESS PARAMETERS
      ( RECORDS DELIMITED BY '\n"'
                         BADFILE SNOW_IMPORT_TEST:'TEST_1.bad'
                         LOGFILE SNOW_IMPORT_TEST:'TEST_1.log'
                         SKIP 1
                         FIELDS TERMINATED BY '","'
                         MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
                                                                  )
      LOCATION
       ( "IMPORT_TEST":'TEST_1.csv'
       )
    )
```

Adding any characters before the \n doesn't return any rows, below is what I want which doesn't work:

```
      ( RECORDS DELIMITED BY '",\n"'
```

Is it possible to use **"** + **,** + **\n** + **"** as records delimiter.

Thanks.

Comment: Seen [this](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9533807800346847751)?

Answer (score 0):

The external table worked by adding \r to the delimiter

```
RECORDS DELIMITED BY '",\r\n"'
```

looks like the csv return character were \r\n not just \n